# Parameters with unknown value

Tags: python, numpy

So to be specific  I m trying to compute the product scalar of two vectors but the problem is both vectors coordinates contain parameters for example

```
 X=[alpha+beta,0,gamma]
 Y=[alpha,beta,alpha]
```

Value of `alpha` and `beta` are unknown so I can't /I don't know how to define them without giving them a specific value

Comment: Well... you can't. I mean, the question boils down to: "I have a number, but I don't know what it is. Can someone tell me what this number is?" and that's not a question anyone other than you can answer.

Comment: If X and Y are a list, you can use indices to refer to those positions. So `def product(x,y):` and then each calculation inside the function uses x[0], x[1], etc...

Comment: Note that your function does not need to know whether x[0] is 4 or alpha or alpha+beta in order to work. Then, once you have the values for alpha, beta, etc you just assign those to the list, as you did in your question.

Comment: What are you expecting here?  There are Python modules that can work on symbolic functions with named parameters, but I wouldn't suggest going there without knowing more about what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Per some of the comments, is it simply a function with three parameters?

```
import numpy as np

def func( alpha, beta, gamma ):
    x = np.array( [ alpha + beta, 0, gamma ] )
    y = np.array( [ alpha, beta ,alpha ] )
    return x @ y
func( 5, 6, 7 )
# 90  = ( 5 + 6 ) * 5 + 5 * 7 = 55 + 35
```